# Creating an HTTP POST Request with Header info using Net::HTTP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, http-headers

Im trying to programmatically post to an html form on the internet.I have managed to create a request with parameters in the request body but I can't figure out how to pass in Http Header attributes using the Net::Http library. Any ideas if this is possible?... Any other library that would do it for me ?

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://test.com/add_comment'),
                          {'static'=>'1', 'entry_id'=>'23942',})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6727

especially lines like:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
req.add_field("X-Forwarded-For", "0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the original question, since this example is for a Get request, but the original question was about how to send a post_form request. Am I missing something?